# How can I declare a module as a function with custom properties ad-hoc in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am working with a pure JavaScript library without any TypeScript declarations, so I have added this (which isn't working):

```
declare module '@drumwork/tone' {
  declare let mod = function (str: string): string
  mod.list = (str: string) => Array<string>
  export default mod
}
```

My functions' implementations are basically like this:

```
function main(str) {
  // return some newly generated string
  return str + str
}

main.list = (str) => [...str]

export default main
```

Given that the implementation is pure JavaScript and is somewhat like that, how do I do a `declare module` in TypeScript?

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) says to do this, but it doesn't do what I'm describing exactly:

```
declare module '@drumwork/tone' {
  export default function (str: string): string
  export function list(str: string): Array<{ i: string; o: string }>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9AVABAglBmBXAdgYwC4EsD2yoHcALTVQqVAQz0IoDcBTKbdQ+gJygAc3tP2t6AZwB0UCGFDoAnnygBhRIPTYAtgDEUGHHgC8UDWiy45uJW0QZsHAGRQA3qChcefNtICMALlhs2FKQA8ZpjIAOYAfE5R0TGxsWBgUACa2IjkVFAUACZZzrz8mELCjlAANphK3gAUZt4wvv5B6GwhEQCUUDqR9X6BwWGR8YkA8hxIhtqCBMSkUCqK6FAARoyYKpyl9Cr0yOj0WcUgAL4A3KCgqKaLuXrjWrhQNc3e-aEddlAlTmz06IhseDMUAA1FAzGdjpkplQpFD5AtVAZ7sgTnE0eioAkoABZChsADWUBYFXSSjhUlScwWpMWykyyFh8EwbCUh1AkGgSKMeDWGy2O3QFG5YgkIAO5TJeiqmD2KkEdQafWarXCHS6TgcIGil2Qgmwm2EpWwoSqAANUAiVHNfoRsFlTW0IdEfn8AVAZVtBBCjudwBBoAAVISLcSgcUVdBVADaAHJ3DGADRQGMeq0AJhjAF02kA). I explained with comments.

Then you should be able to default export your function as a module.